# Lazy loading UITableView with multiple images in each cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, lazy-loading

I am using lazy loading to show images on a table view.
But I need to create a tableview with multiple images in every cell.Which can be scrolled.
All images are loaded from server only
How can I create this without any lagging for table scrolling ?
Is there any tutorial available for this

Comment: Create the needed UIImageView's for your cell and use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage for async downloading of images.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h). It downloads image from server and save it to device cache.
Also if you don't want save it to cache then you might have a look at `AFNetworking`.

Comment: There is an option available NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed in AFNetworking. Check that.

Comment: your ans explicitly implies AFNetworking does not use cacheing..which i pointed out as far as checking out is concerned i have done many tweaks in it to disable and enable caching to show updated images etc..

Answer (score 2):

There is another option. Using `GCD (Grand Central Dispatch)`.

Example Code :

```
// Get the filename to load.
    NSString *imageFilename = [imageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *imagePath = [imageFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageFilename];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:imageFilename];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[cell imageView] setImage:image];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        });
    });
```

Use the same for showing multiple images. Using this will increase the performance of loading tableview definitely.

Refer [this](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/) to know more about `GCD`

Comment: @Vidya Vasudev: did my post help ?

Comment: Better than SDWebImage. No weird fit when loaded image doesn't have the same aspect ratio with the placeholder. 0 dependencies. And I don't really need caching, I just need a solution that doesn't lock up the app while images are loading. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView .Easy to download images asyncronously from server.