# iOS UITableViewCell reload optimisation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a question about table view cells.

In cell I have an `UIImageView`. This view loads from web service with getter:

```
- (UIImageView *)imageView
{
    if (!_ imageView)
    {
        _imageView = [[TurnipImageView alloc] init];

        _imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    [_imageView loadImageViewFromWebService];

    return _imageView;
}
```

When I add `[_imageView loadImageViewFromWebService];` call inside of `if (!_ imageView)` statement, image view is not loaded correctly.

When I scroll table view, cells are reloading as well as image views and causing lags in scrolling.

Maybe anyone knows how to optimise this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try lazy loading of the table view :
here is the sample : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

also have a look at this : 
[Lazy loading UITableView with multiple images in each cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063580/lazy-loading-uitableview-with-multiple-images-in-each-cell)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    //perform download on background thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       //assign image to imageview on main thread, UI operations should be carried on main thread
    });
});



- (UIImageView *)imageView
{
    if (!_ imageView)
    {
        _imageView = [[TurnipImageView alloc] init];

        _imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    //perform download on background thread

        [_imageView loadImageViewFromWebService];
    });
    return _imageView;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Does this first block needs to be added? O get error: `Use of undeclared identifier 'QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND'`