# Async load multiple images to single cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, afnetworking, cell

I have a problem with loading of 5 images to each cell of `TableView`. I use `AFNetworking` for download and `setImageWithUrl` method for `imageView`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < urls.count; i++) {
    [self.photoImageView[i] setImageWithURL:urls[i]];
}
```

`TableView` very brakes when I scroll it. But when i try to load 1 or 2  no brakes when scrolling.
[image]
How to correct download images without brakes?

Comment: image without breaks?

Comment: Try setting `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

Comment: it break cause image size bigger so try to reduce it.

Answer (score 2):

I think's it's helpful for you below the code work for me.

First fall you use this library [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
then implement below code.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
...
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SDWebImage as discussed by @Ravi. You can use use the above code in your for loop to display all 5 images asynchronously , without blocking main thread.

```
for (int i = 0; i < urls.count; i++) {
[self.photoImageView[i] sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urls[i]]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
}
```

If you dont want to use any third party libraries, you can also use GCD for the same. Check this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063580/lazy-loading-uitableview-with-multiple-images-in-each-cell).

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

If you see UIImage + AFNetworking class,It internally loads image using Async NSOperations.Try loading image with specific dimensions.It will download image of that size & could improve scrolling performance.

```
NSMutableString *newURLPath = [NSMutableString stringWithString[exercise.imageURL absoluteString]];
 [newURLPath appendFormat:@"?width=200&"];
 [newURLPath appendFormat:@"height=200"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`For downloading the Asynchronous image from url, use any of these library for improving the scroll performance`

**[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)** - Asynchronous image downloader with cache support as a UIImageView category.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
...
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:URL
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
];
```

**[PINRemoteImage](https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage)** - It download a progressive jpeg and get attractive blurred updates.

For in your case, you can go for SDWebImage.

```
For Advance Concept, you could look into this one.
```

**[AsyncDisplayKit](https://github.com/facebookarchive/AsyncDisplayKit)**  - Smooth asynchronous user interfaces for iOS apps

Even recently, Pinterest was built on top of AsyncDisplayKit to Keeps UIs smooth and responsive.
Read this article for more info: https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/re-architecting-pinterest-039-s-ios-app-e0a2d34a6ac2